# Rename wp login plugin not able to change login url for all innersite at once

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using wordpress multi site installation. To avoid brute force attacks i opted to install the plugin rename wp-login.php

My problem is when I change the url on the main dashboard(ex: mainsite/customlogin) the inner sites still has the login permalink as "innersites/login".

It is hard to change login permalink for each site. is ther any other way, please advise.

plugin reference url: http://wordpress.org/support/plugin/rename-wp-login

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Janneke I have already posted this in plugins forum also. 
posted here also because this is the place where i get answers for everything quickly.

Finally this hack resolved my problem.
In plugin file : rename-wp-login.php
line number: 125
change the code as below

---

```
if ( ! get_option( 'rwl_page' ) || get_option( 'rwl_page' ) == '' ) {
switch_to_blog(1);
update_option( 'rwl_page', wp_unique_post_slug( get_option( 'rwl_page' ), 0, 'publish', 'page', 0 ) );

restore_current_blog();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rename wp-login.php now also has an option in the network admin to set a network wide default. This updates the login link for all your sites at once, though it can be overwritten for individual sites.